# how to execute a command on a timer

Tags: java, timer

I wrote a program that creates a file of any desired size by populating it with zeroes. I am trying to optimize it by only flushing it every few seconds (lets go with 5 seconds) instead of every loop. When I try to use Timer, the code `output.flush();` gives me an error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    fileMaker fp = new fileMaker();

    Writer output = null;
    File f = new File(args[1]);
    output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(f, true));
    output.write("0");

    long size = fp.getFileSize(args[1]);

    long mem = Long.parseLong(args[0]) * 1073741824; //1 Gigabyte = 1073741824 bytes


    while (size < mem)
    {
        output.write("");

        TimerTask fileProcessTask = new TimerTask()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                output.flush();
                processFile();

            }
        };

        Timer tm = new Timer();
        tm.schedule(fileProcessTask, 5000L);


        size = fp.getFileSize(args[1]);

        double avg = (double) size / mem * 100;

        System.out.println(avg + "% complete");
    }
    output.close();
    System.out.println("Finished at " + size / 1073741824 + " Gigabyte(s)");

}
```

Comment: What type of `Timer`? Was it a swing timer?

Comment: @Legend I'll edit my OP with the timer code that I tried

Comment: Try using a swing timer with the action listener implementation.

Comment: Where is the code that opens `output` for writing?

Comment: @Legend: the code and the tags doesn't indicate that swing is used. Why would he use a Swing timer?

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to write anything in the file at all. Why don't you just use a BufferedWriter and let it flush when it wants to?

Comment: and you're also creating a new timertask and timer in each iteration.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak I'll add it in the OP

Comment: and what exactly is the "error" you get?

Comment: @JBNizet It writes a bunch of zeroes, I literally overloaded it so it appears as `("")`

Comment: What does that mean? Your code shows that you're calling output.write("") on a BufferedWriter. That doesn't write anything to the file. Do you realize that the buffered writer flushes itself automatically when its buffer is full?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with the code you provided:

- You are creating a new `TimerTask` and a new `Timer` every iteration of your while loop. You only need one Timer to schedule several TimerTasks
- You also only need one single `TimerTask` and use `Timer.schedule` to repeatedly execute the task (like so `timer.schedule(someTimerTask, 5000, 5000);` [start in 5s, loop every 5s])
- You'll probably have to declare `output` as `final` as you're accessing it in an anonymous inner class
- Why are you actually writing `"0"` and `""`? You'll probably only want to write zero-bytes, not empty characters (and probably want to use a `FileOutputStream` directly)

Answer (score 0):

The reason, why you are getting an error in `output.flush` is because you never cancel the task, once you fall out the `while` loop.

The first thing you do after the `while` loop, is to `close` the output, so the next time the task is run by the timer it has closed stream, hence the exception you are seen.